# How to set exe icon using AssemblyBuilder?

Tags: .net, winapi, icons

Given that I am generating an exe application with AssemblyBuilder, how do I set an **icon** to it?

I think I should be using

```
System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineUnmanagedResource
```

Is there an example how to do it?

---

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380599(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could also change the icon after saving the EXE using the Win32 resource APIs BeginUpdateResource, UpdateResource and EndUpdateResource. See [Change WPF Assembly Icon from Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797461/change-wpf-assembly-icon-from-code) (which isn't WPF specific).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need DefineUnmanagedResource().  The file you pass must be in the .RES file format.  That requires the rc.exe Windows SDK tool.  To create one, start by creating a text file named test.rc with this content:

```
 100 ICON test.ico
```

Where test.ico is the name of a file that contains the icon.  Start the Visual Studio Command Prompt and use this command

```
 rc test.rc
```

That creates a test.res file.  Pass its path to DefineUnmanagedResource(), your final .exe contains the icon resource.

Note that this is not verify practical, the target machine probably won't have the Windows SDK installed and you cannot redistribute rc.exe.  But you could distribute the .res file.

Comment: I wonder if it were possible to create a template "res" file and then swap the icon in it?

Comment: The .res file format is not documented.  You could figure out the offset of the binary .ico data but you'll run into trouble when the replacement .ico is not the same size.

Comment: It's been 7 years since this was posted.  There is documentation of the resource header format now:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648027(v=vs.85).aspx  It require splitting an icon into it's various parts and converting the icon header into GROUP_ICON resource, but I managed to find enough documentation to convert an .ico to a .res file.

Comment: Also, it's important to differentiate the version that takes a file path from the version that takes a byte[].  The file path version imports the .res format, but the byte[] version is dumped directly into the executable as-is (which means defining a resource directory structure, which involves virtual addresses, which I'm not even sure is possible).

Answer (score -1):

You need to set up an ResourceManager by defining an `IResourceWriter` and write to it, then read in the icon as bytes and set it, according to this documentation from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csz77dt9.aspx), I guess the code would look something like this, as I have not done this before, judging by the code sample, after you save the assembly, add the unmanaged resource and name it as 'app.ico':

```
// Defines a standalone managed resource for this assembly.
IResourceWriter myResourceWriter = myAssembly.DefineResource("myResourceIcon",
         "myResourceIcon.ico", "MyAssemblyResource.resources", 
         ResourceAttributes.Public);
myResourceWriter.AddResource("app.ico", "Testing for the added resource");

myAssembly.Save(myAssembly.GetName().Name + ".dll");

// Defines an unmanaged resource file for this assembly.
bool bSuccess = false;
byte[] iconB = null;
using (System.IO.FileStream fStream = new FileStream("icon.ico", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)){
    iconB = new byte[(int)fStream.Length];
    int nRead = fStream.Read(out iconB, 0, iconB.Length);
    if (nRead == iconB.Length) bSuccess = true;
}
if (bSuccess){
    myAssembly.DefineUnmanagedResource(iconB);
}
```